# Number of touchmove events severely reduced on Android 2.3.3

Tags: javascript, android, events, mobile, swipe

I am currently working on the redesign of a website following the responsive design + mobile first approach.

I am trying to detect swipe events using JS on touch-enabled devices. For this purpose, I am using the following code:

```
document.addEventListener ('touchstart', function(event) {
    //Get initial finger coords
}, false);

document.addEventListener ('touchmove', function(event) {
    //Update final finger coords
}, false);

document.addEventListener ('touchend', function(event) {
    //Compare initial and final coords, trigger swipe events if necessary
}, false);
```

I have tested this code on an iPad 1, an iPhone 4 and several devices running Android 2.2.1, and the result when I drag my finger on the screen is what I am expecting:  the `touchmove` event fires several times (it can easily rise up to a hundred when doing a long gesture).

The problem comes when I test it on an Android 2.3.3 device (I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S2). Using its native broswer, the amount of `touchmove` events is reduced to only 1 (or rarely 2).

Am I doing something wrong or is it supposed to behave like that? Has anybody found the same problem? I was unable to find documentation about the behaviour of `touchmove` events in this version of Andriod.

You can test it here (using a touch-enabled device): http://jsfiddle.net/xs5BG/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that galaxy S2 doesn't fire the touchmove after the scrolling starts to work. If you do a preventDefault it fires the events as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your jsFiddle example with my HTC Desire Z (running 2.3.3) i get many more than just one touchmove event - as desired. So i am unable to reproduce your actual problem with this device, although on the same API Level :( Interestingly enough your code also shows the problem that i am experiencing on my current project: The first touchmove event seems to have some kind of a threshold:

Putting the finger down and only moving a tiny bit will give 0 touchmove events... once over the threshold it will trigger touchmove events in intervals of milliseconds as it then recognises each and every pixel distance of a move (like it should do). Maybe this could be related to your phenomenon, respectively do you see this on your 2.3.3 device as well?

Answer (score 0):

On many android versions if you don't preventDefault on touchstart the Android device will go into default scrolling mode and stops sending touch events to webview. So you would need to

```
document.addEventListener ('touchstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Now all the touch events will fire, but default scrolling will be disabled.

There is a shim to overcome this issue that emulates a swipe gesture https://github.com/TNT-RoX/android-swipe-shim